# How to create custom function for list of dataframes from split

Tags: r, list

I'm new to functions and just discovered split. 
I have a list of dataframes from the split function. For each dataframe I would like to count the number of a specific regular expression and dump the overall count in a vector (which I then intend to add to a matrix for all the dataframes).

Although its easy to create the counts, I don't know how to then translate this into a function that will do the same thing for all the dataframes in the list:

Here is my attempt so far

```
lapply(PClst, function(x) nrow(x[grepl(".*denoma.*", x$Dx, perl = TRUE, ]))
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in x$Dx : $ operator is invlaid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of PClst ?

Comment: Fyi, it's much better to present a reproducible example (like Nathan did in his answer).

Comment: Reading the error message is quite useful. R is telling you that the error is not in the list, but in the PClst object, which happens to be a atomic vector and, because of that, doesn't fit in the 'x$Dx' syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we could do something like this:

```
list <- split(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
sapply(list, function(x) sum(grepl("2", x$carb)))
```

we would get a named vector as output:

```
4 6 8 
6 0 4
```

Comment: so does sum give you the count of the number of rows containing the grep?

Comment: yes, `sum()` on a `logical` vector returns the total number of `TRUE`'s

Comment: More standard would be to use tapply instead of split-sapply: `tapply(grepl("2", mtcars$carb), mtcars$cyl, sum)`